# React-Redux data not reaching console after refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The web page displays correctly on the browser once, but after refreshing the page, the data goes away and all I see is an empty object when looking at the console. However, by looking at my Redux DevTools I can see the payload going into my action and the state in my reducer updating after every refresh. So it seems like my state is in fact updating after every refresh but I can't pinpoint why the data is not reaching my console after I refresh.

Only way I can get the data to reach my browser again is by resaving the component.

Answer (score 2):

`console.log(stockData);` is only ever called when your component is first mounted because `fetchStock()` is only ever called on first mount. Your `useEffect` has an empty dependency array, which will cause it to only be called once. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

If you intend for the effect to run on every render, remove the dependency array, or better yet, have it be dependent on `stockData`, which I think is what you are after.

It's also possible (since you mentioned a browser refresh which would remount your component anyways) that you are in something of a race condition where `stockData` has not yet been populated in the store before the component is first mounted. Having the useEffect dependent on `stockData` also resolves this scenario. If this is your case, you should probably add a guard clause to not hit your API before the stockData is available.

Edit: Additional note, you are performing state updates after an asynchronous operation. This can lead to memory leaks in React. I suggest you look at adding a cleanup function to your useEffect that sets an abort flag and condition your state updates on that. I usually do something like the following.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let aborted = false;
  const doSomethingAsync = async (theStateData) => {
    const result = await myAPICall(theStateData);
    if (result.flag && !aborted) {
      setSomeState(result.value);
    }
  };

  if (myState) {
    doSomethingAsync(myState);
  }
  return () => {
    aborted = true;
  };
}, [myState]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried both removing the dependency array and also including stockData in the dependency array. In both cases it starts making endless API calls before I can even refresh, to the point where I have to stop the app to not exceed daily API call limits. Is this what you were referring to when you mentioned adding a guard clause?

Comment: I have also tried the cleanup function with no luck. What's interesting is that if I run this same component using only React without Redux involved, then I don't have any issues. I'm not sure what else I can try at this point.

Comment: If what you say is true, then you have other issues. It sounds like your component is continually re-rendering (maybe stockData is being pushed new information continually)? This sounds like some broader architectural problems that I'll have to bow out of. Good luck.